# How can I fix crash when tap to select row after scrolling the tableview?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I have a table view like this:

[image]

when the user tap one row, I want uncheck the last row and check the selected row. So I wrote my code like this:
(for example my lastselected = 0)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        var lastIndexPath:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: lastSelected, inSection: 0)
        var lastCell = self.diceFaceTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(lastIndexPath) as! TableViewCell
        var cell = self.diceFaceTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! TableViewCell


        lastCell.checkImg.image = UIImage(named: "uncheck")

        cell.checkImg.image = UIImage(named: "check")

        lastSelected = indexPath.row

}
```

every thing working fine when I tap a row without scrolling. I realize that when I run the code and scrolling the table immediately and selected the one row. My program will crash with error:
"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

the error show in this line:

[image]

I don't know what wrong in here?

Comment: how many Section you used in tableview?

Comment: what if you println the lastIIndexPath - I think you're selecting something that has already been reused

Comment: I only have one section in my Tableview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are using reusable cells when you try to select a cell that is not in the screen anymore the app will crash as the cell is no long exist in memory, try this:

```
if let lastCell = self.diceFaceTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(lastIndexPath) as! TableViewCell{
    lastCell.checkImg.image = UIImage(named: "uncheck")
}
//update the data set from the table view with the change in the icon
//for the old and the new cell
```

This code will update the check box if the cell is currently in the screen. If it is not currently on the screen when you get the cell to reused (`dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier`) you should set it properly before display. To do so you will need to update the data set of the table view to contain the change.

Comment: @HieuDucPham Glad you understand the problem, sometimes the reusable cells can be trick! Good luck finishing your app!

Answer (score 0):

Better approach will be storing whole indexPath. not only the row. Try once i think this will work. I had the same problem in one of my app.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var lastCell = self.diceFaceTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(lastSelectedIndexPath) as! TableViewCell
    var cell = self.diceFaceTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    lastCell.checkImg.image = UIImage(named: "uncheck")
    cell.checkImg.image = UIImage(named: "check")

    lastSelectedIndexPath = indexPath
}
```

EDIT: or you can try this.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var lastCell = self.diceFaceTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    lastCell.checkImg.image = UIImage(named: "uncheck")
}
```

Comment: I tried to store the whole indexPath but still got the error.

Comment: same error. also I tried to setup a lastSelectedIndexPath like this: "            var lastSelectedIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)" because I only have one section.

Comment: same problem although tried both of your code.  As I 've just learn from Icaro above , the problem is I'm setting the cell that has been reused so I set the data before it's appear. So I got the problem.